# WPF-'Index out of Range' error for a datagrid which is placed in the second tabitem of tabcontrol (but it works fine if placed in first tabitem)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tabcontrol

So I have WPF window with one **tabcontrol** which has 4 **tabitems**.

When placing a datagrid in **first** tab item, and binding to datatable,it works fine like so:

```
 private void LoadServices()
    {
        if (serviceData.GetAllServices(currentID) != null)
        {
            dataGridServices.ItemsSource = serviceData.GetAllServices(currentID).DefaultView;
            dataGridServices.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
```

(btw I am calling the method above in **Window_ContentRendered** event and it works fine).

I then add another datagrid in the **second** tabitem with the EXACT same code but now I get the error on the line below: "*Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')'*":

```
dataGridServices.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

When debugging and hovering over the **ItemSource** property, I can see that there are three columns there, so how can it be index out of range? By the way the method for binding to the second datagrid is the same as above and I am also calling this from **Window_ContentRendered** event too.

(Just to be clear, when I am not hiding the specific column, the data loads fine with the column names too which are defined in stored procedure)

Is there something unique in the way datagrids and tabcontrols work together in WPF?

LATEST CODE:

XAML:

```
 <TabControl x:Name="tabControl">
            <TabItem  x:Name="FirstTabItem" Header="First">
                <DataGrid  x:Name="datagridServicesFirstTab">
                </DataGrid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem  x:Name="SecondTabItem" Header="Second">
                <DataGrid  x:Name="datagridServices" AutoGeneratedColumns="OnLoaded" >
                </DataGrid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

Event Handler Method:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadServices();
    }
```

Data Method:

```
private void LoadServices()
    {
        if (serviceData.GetAllServices(currentID) != null)
        {
            datagridServices.ItemsSource = serviceData.GetAllServices(currentID).DefaultView;
            datagridServices.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you create the columns explicitely or did you specify AutoGenerateColumns?

Comment: @KlausGütter For both datagrids, 'AutoGenerateColumns' set to true

Comment: I'm not sure but it could well be that the columns are only generated once the data grid gets visible, i.e. for the one on the second tab once the second tab gets active.

Answer (score 0):

> When debugging and hovering over the ItemSource property, I can see that there are three columns there, so how can it be index out of range?

Probably because the columns of the `DataGrid` has not yet been generated. The content of a tab item is not rendered until you select that tab.

Move your code from `Window_ContentRenderer` to a `AutoGeneratedColumns` event handler for the second `DataGrid`:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadServices();
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TabItem Header="second...">
    <DataGrid ... AutoGeneratedColumns="OnLoaded" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work either, I get the same 'index out of range' error

Comment: So try `AutoGeneratedColumns` instead. See my answer. When this event is rasied, there should be some columns.

Comment: the 'AutoGeneratedColumns' event does not fire (again because it is on the second tab). When I attached the same event to the datagrid on the first tab, it fired successfully

Comment: Did you select the second tab? It's not expected to fire until you do this...

Comment: You need to realize that there are no columns until the `DataGrid` is actually displayed.

Comment: Yes @mm8 I selected second tab, but the 'AutoGeneratedColumns' event does not fire. And yes I have realized that there are no columns until displayed. Which is why I am trying to find an event which will load the columns until the datagrid is displayed. So far the above solutions have not worked unfortunately.

Comment: So you are not auto generating columns then?

Comment: 'AutoGenerateColumns' property is set to true for this datagrid (same with all my datagrids within this app)

Comment: Does it contain any data?

Comment: It does yes. So when I remove the line to hide the first column, everything loads nicely, but when I try to hide the first column (or any column for that matter) the error appears

Comment: Then you are trying to hide it to soon. Can you post your current code including the XAML?

Comment: You need to set the `ItemsSource` somewhere else for the colums to be generated in the first place...where are you doing this?

Comment: The ItemsSource is set in a data access class which pulls data from the database. It is the same method that is used for the datagrid on the first tabitem. The method returns a datatable that I then bind to this datagrid.